# All node, globally installed npm commands stopped working

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, npm-install

All node, globally installed npm commands stopped working.
They do not work when I re-install locally either. 
node server.js works, but crashed because my mongod command does not work.
I think I screwed up my enviro PATH variables.

Can a PC user take a screenshot of their enviro variables (or just post the relavant one) so I can try to re-create it?

When i try to re-install I get this error:
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

I had a similar problem with webpack not working and we were able to spot an irregularity in the path, which happened to be on my desktop and I cleaned up my desktop and problem solved. Can anyone see anything irregular about the path in the first warning>   Or just know how to get my commands working again?

Comment: do u still have your package.json file ?

Comment: {
  "name": "flashcards",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}

Comment: This "flashcards" project was the project I was working on when the problem started, but the npm commands do not work on any project on any directory.  I swear the path to my node modules is just screwed up. I think I deleted something from my environment path variables.

Comment: SOLUTION: I did a system restore using:      In Windows 10 navigate to Start > Settings > Update & Security > Recovery
Under Advanced Startup, click Restart Now
Once the computer reboots into Advanced Startup, click Troubleshoot >> then system recover from a date/time prior to problem
Click Refresh Your PC.  All my npm commands work again!!!